# R- merge dataframes based on recent dates

Tags: r, date, merge

I have two dataframes:

In DF1, for every `ID`, the `param` have been recorded on various dates.
In DF2, for every `ID`, a number of dates are given.
For every `ID`, I would like to get all the corresponding `param` and `value` from DF1, depending on the dates:
either the `value` that corresponds to the most recent `date1` (in `DF1`) *before* `date2` (in `DF2`) for a given param or
If there is no such `date1`, the most recent `value` *after* `date2`.

`DF1` is (I have marked with * the correct rows for the result ):

```
  ID      date1 param  value
1 id1   1/1/2020    pA pA_1_1
2 id1   2/1/2020    pA pA_1_2 *
3 id1  17/1/2020    pA pA_1_3
4 id1  20/1/2020    pB pB_1_1 *
5 id1  21/1/2020    pB pB_1_2
6 id2 21/12/2022    pA pA_2_1 *
7 id2 22/12/2022    pA pA_2_2 
8 id2 18/12/2022    pB pB_2_1 *
9 id2 19/12/2022    pB pB_2_2
```

`DF2` is:

```
   ID      date2
1 id1  15/1/2020
2 id2 20/12/2020
```

The result should be:

```
   ID      date2 param  value      date1
1 id1  15/1/2020    pA pA_1_2   2/1/2020
2 id1  15/1/2020    pB pB_1_1  20/1/2020
3 id2 20/12/2020    pA pA_2_1 21/12/2022
4 id2 20/12/2020    pB pB_2_1 18/12/2022
```

Code to reproduce the `DF1` and `DF2`:

```
DF1= data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                ID = c("id1","id1","id1","id1",
                       "id1","id2","id2","id2","id2"),
             date1 = c("1/1/2020","2/1/2020",
                       "17/1/2020","20/1/2020","21/1/2020","21/12/2022",
                       "22/12/2022","18/12/2022","19/12/2022"),
             param = c("pA", "pA", "pA", "pB", "pB", "pA", "pA", "pB", "pB"),
             value = c("pA_1_1","pA_1_2","pA_1_3",
                       "pB_1_1","pB_1_2","pA_2_1","pA_2_2","pB_2_1","pB_2_2")
)

DF2=data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                ID = c("id1", "id2"),
             date2 = c("15/1/2020", "20/12/2020")
)
```

Comment: Pls check if for ID2 param pB should be the row 9 and not row 8 the one selected. As row8 is the minimum date after date2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution. I'm sure there is a way to write this with less code (using one dataframe instead of two and later merging). But I don't know righ now.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
# Get before date2
before <-  DF1 %>%
  left_join(DF2,by = "ID") %>% 
  mutate(diff = dmy(date1)-dmy(date2)) %>% 
  mutate(Grp = data.table::rleid(param)) %>%
  filter(diff < 0) %>%
  group_by(Grp) %>%
  filter(diff == max(diff)) %>% 
  ungroup
# Get after date2
after <- DF1 %>%
  left_join(DF2,by = "ID") %>% 
  mutate(diff = dmy(date1)-dmy(date2)) %>% 
  mutate(Grp = data.table::rleid(param)) %>%
  filter(diff > 0) %>%
  group_by(Grp) %>%
  filter(! Grp %in% before$Grp, diff == min(diff)) %>% 
  ungroup

result <- bind_rows(before,after) %>% 
  select(ID,date2, param, value, date1) %>%
  arrange(ID, param)
```

Explanation: I'm using lubridate library to compare the dates. I do the same process to create two dataframes - first one (before df) for groups which accomplish first condition (closest date in DF1 before date2 in DF2), second one (after df) is for groups which do the other way round (closest date in DF1 after date2 in DF2).

I will explain first:

```
# Get before date2

    before <-  DF1 %>%
    left_join(DF2,by = "ID") %>% 
    mutate(diff = dmy(date1)-dmy(date2)) %>% 
    mutate(Grp = data.table::rleid(param)) %>%
    filter(diff < 0) %>%
    group_by(Grp) %>%
    filter(diff == max(diff)) %>% 
    ungroup
```

Here, we merge DF1 and DF2 by ID, so rows with same ID have the same date2. Then, we calculate the differences date1-date2 - first we convert characters to date using `dmy()`. Therefore, dates before date2 will be a negative difference. With `data.table::rleid(param)` we enumerate subgroups with different ID & param, so we can know the subgroups. Then we can group by then and filter by them.

At the end:

```
result <- bind_rows(before,after) %>% 
  select(ID,date2, param, value, date1) %>%
  arrange(ID, param)
```

We bind the two dataframe by rows and select the columns you are looking for, to delete the columns we created to operate with (group and filter).
PS: I added arrange() to make sure the final df is sorted by ID and param values.

Comment: Many thanks RobertoT. You are right about your comment, too. I made the correction in the post.

Comment: @tzema It will be great if you edit as well in your expected df result to clarify (19 -> 18). In case other people search for something related.